# Why can't send binary data from service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to send form data with image(binary) from service worker.

Send form data without image, it's works fine.
But if the form data contains an image(binary), service worker send nothing without error.

And.. I found some problems

- Choose korean file name => This problem occurs
- Choose English(ascii characters) => Work fine

  Strangely, both work well without service worker

I tried restart browser, unregister service worker, add Content-Type header to axios request and more things :(

I prepared the below my code. I don't know why work like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', paperTitle.value);
formData.append('content', paperContent.value);
formData.append('image', paperImage.files[0]);

// Send form data
axios.post('/api/addPost', formData)
  .then(({ data }) => {
     // Success
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```
// Service worker - fetch handler
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

[image: without image]

without image (work fine)

[image: with image]

with image - korean, chinese etc... filename (form data was gone)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', paperTitle.value);
formData.append('content', paperContent.value);
// formData.append('image', paperImage.files[0]); // before
formData.append('file', paperImage.files[0]); // after
```

But still I don't know why only the `file` key works.

Comment: As a hint, you could encode binary data with base64 and transport as a string. You will a slightly overflow, but can be worth it.

Comment: I have considered that but have not tried. Thanks for the comments :)